# Reset value by UITableView sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am building a personal budget app that tracks my purchases. I have an `NSDictionary` of `NSArray` that looks like this:

```
{
    46 =    (
                {
            DATE = "11/14/2019";
            ID = 21;
            PLACE = Kroger;
            PRICE = "23.32";
        },
                {
            DATE = "11/14/2019";
            ID = 22;
            PLACE = Walmart;
            PRICE = "12.54";
        }
    );
    47 =     (
                {
            DATE = "11/18/2019";
            ID = 23;
            PLACE = Cinco;
            PRICE = "65.32";
        }
    );
}
```

The keys in the `NSDictionary` are determined by `strftime` using `%W`. Basically I have a set limit I can spend per week (i.e. 190) and I want in each `titleForHeaderInSection:` to have a total value that is determined by each field's `PRICE` in each key.

I currently have the following on the app:

[image: App]

The following calculate the `NSDictionary` listed above along with the total value:

Note: arrFoodInfo is a `NSDictionary` of *just* the entries without the week numbers

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in self.arrFoodInfo) {
        NSString *date = [dict objectForKey:@"DATE"];
        [totalPrices addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"PRICE"]];

        for (NSString *price in totalPrices) {
            if ([totalPrices containsObject:price]) {
                _sumPrices += [price floatValue]; // Calculates total value
                [totalPrices removeObject:price];
            }
        }

        NSDateFormatter *SDF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]
                                 init];
        [SDF setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        [SDF setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
        NSDate *convertedDate = [SDF dateFromString:date];

        NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:convertedDate];

        NSInteger week = dateComponents.weekOfYear;
        NSInteger index = week;
        NSNumber *key = @(index);

        NSMutableArray *weekArray = weeksDictionary[key];
        if (!weekArray) {
            weekArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            weeksDictionary[key] = weekArray;
        }
        [weekArray addObject:dict];
    }
```

At the moment, I am getting the total of each `PRICE` but the total value should be different per section. What is the best option to determine this?

Comment: Use a custom class to represent that, a class with a property weekNumber, a property total, an array of purchases (which would have a property price, an property id, another one place and a NSDate one).

Comment: @Larme I didn't even think of that and I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @Larme How would you go about creating this custom class and implementing it? I am still trying to learn Obj-C but I have previous experience in other languages. Are there any examples you can provide on how to accomplish this?